# How do I debug/troubleshoot an event not firing?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, mvvm-light

In one of my views, I have 2 event triggers on a TabControl:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectedItemChanged">
        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding TestCommand}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="TabClosed">
        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding CloseCurrentWorkspaceCommand}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Here is the code for the command bindings:

```
RelayCommand _t;
public RelayCommand TestCommand { get { return _t ?? (_t = new RelayCommand(foo)); } }
void foo()
{
    // This is just to see if the event is firing.
    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Fired");
}

RelayCommand _closeWorkspaceCommand;
public RelayCommand CloseCurrentWorkspaceCommand
{
    get { return _closeWorkspaceCommand ?? (_closeWorkspaceCommand = new RelayCommand(CloseWorkspace)); }
}

void CloseWorkspace()
{
    // Workspaces is a ObservableCollection<WorkspaceViewModel>
    Workspaces.Remove(SelectedItem);
}
```

The SelectedItemChanged event never fires when the selected item (or index) is changed. Also changing the event to SelectedIndexChanged has no effect. The TabClosed event fires without a problem. The SelectedIndex and SelectedItem bindings are updating accordingly.

I've checked the output Window and I don't see any binding errors or anything that might suggest the binding is wrong.

How can I start to diagnose why this event won't fire?

Full code of control:

```
<wpf:TabControlExt Grid.Row="1" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Workspaces}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
    SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}">
    <wpf:TabControlExt.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </wpf:TabControlExt.ItemTemplate>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectedItemChanged">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding TestCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="TabClosed">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding CloseCurrentWorkspaceCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</wpf:TabControlExt>
```

Comment: `<wpf:TabControlExt` - what library is this from?

Comment: Syncfusion.http://help.syncfusion.com/wpf/tabext/overview

Comment: Since you have SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}" , why then fire SelectedItemChanged ? If SelectedIndex is well binded then all will be Ok

Comment: I've tried the SelectedIndexChanged event, but it still won't fire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it.

It turns out I was binding to the wrong event. I should have been binding to `SelectionChanged`. I only found this out when going through the Triggers pane in Blend. It didn't give me the option to pick `SelectedIndexChanged` or `SelectedItemChanged`.

Although in hindsight, SelectionChanged makes more sense since when the item changes, the index changes, and you can't rearrange tabs in the control as far as I know.

So the correct code is:

```
<i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
    <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding TestCommand}"/>
</i:EventTrigger>
```